# Umbraco7 SMTP Success message callback ERROR

Tags: smtpclient, umbraco7

The form is sending but the problem is the Success message not showing even though the ex.Message Value is Null it should be printing the "Form submitted successfully." but it did not.

And when the ex.Message is not Null .. the error message is working it print "Error submiting message."

need help, Thanks in advance!

Controller.cs

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       return CurrentUmbracoPage();

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add("test@gmail.com");
message.Subject = "New Contact request";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(model.Email, model.Name);
message.Body = model.Message;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com", 26);
try
{
    smtp.Send(message); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    if (ex.Message == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Success = "Form submitted successfully.";
    }
    else {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error submiting message.";
    }
    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the email is sent successfully there is no exception to catch, which is probably why your message does not show up.

Instead, move that message to the try block after .Send, that should do it.

EDIT: Also, I believe that your return statement should be moved outside the try-catch block.

Comment: thanks for reply. I try your suggestion
try{ smtp.Send(message); ViewBag.Success = "Form submitted successfully.";  }  catch (Exception ex) { ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error submiting message."; } return CurrentUmbracoPage();

But still not showing the Success message ? i try alot of position of that code. still not get the answer.

Comment: Strange. Are you "printing" both ViewBag.Success and ViewBag.ErrorMessage on the page? Why not use the same (like ViewBag.Message) for both success and error message?

Comment: yeah sorry for that, i have tried now use both ViewBag.ErrorMessage
still not showing :/ .

Comment: Here is now my code 'try{ smtp.Send(message); ViewBag.Message = "Form submitted successfully."; } catch (Exception ex) { ViewBag.Message = ex.Message; } return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();' Still not showing any idea?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm out of ideas :-( Not in front of a computer to test either.

Comment: ,I found the missing code to make it work :), your idea is great only missed some code on try and catch, just add 
"return CurrentUmbracoPage();" after each ViewBag.Message and it work :) thanks alot. Godbless